# Gravity function Error in pygame: TypeError: 'float' object is not callable

Tags: python

This is my player.py.  The gravity function is giving me an error and I'm not sure why.

File "/Users/josh/Desktop/platformer/player.py", line 39, in update
self.gravity()
TypeError: 'float' object is not callable

```
import pygame
class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self,position):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = pygame.Surface((32,60))
        self.image.fill('red')
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(topleft = position)

        # Player movement
        self.direction = pygame.math.Vector2(0,0)
        self.gravity = 0.8
        self.jump_speed = -16
        self.speed = 5

    def get_input(self):
        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

        if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
            self.direction.x = 1 
        elif keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
            self.direction.x = -1
        else:
            self.direction.x = 0

        if keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
            self.jump()
    
    def gravity(self):
        self.direction.y += self.gravity
        self.rect.y += self.direction.y

    def jump(self):
        self.direction.y = self.jump_speed


    def update(self):
        self.get_input()
        self.rect.x += self.direction.x * self.speed
        self.gravity()
```

Comment: I'm not sure why def update() is not colored like the other methods.  In my VS code it is

Comment: In `__init__` you set `self.gravity=0.8`, so it's now a float

Answer (score 2):

Because you defined the property `self.gravity = 0.8`, please rename like `self.gravity_value = 0.8`
When this happens, find keyword by `CTRL + F` is the best way